# Option for user whether to uninstall previous version of the product

Tags: windows-installer, installscript, installshield-2012

I am creating installer using InstallShield 12 and would like to give option to user, say a checkbox whether user want to uninstall or keep the previous version and could install the new  version.

Do anyone having any idea how could I achieve the above?

I added a check box on a dialog and added a property and if user selects it then uninstall the previous version otherwise go ahead with new version without uninstalling the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are describing is referred to in the MSDN documentation to as [Installing Multiple Instances of Products and Patches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/5147ecbd-c395-4a8f-972d-f5c5b2173eff). You will need to author an Instance Transform (basically a product code transform) because if a product code remains unchanged, only one instance can be installed in the machine context and only one instance can be installed in each user context.

There is some information how to author and apply instance transforms here:

[Authoring Multiple Instances with Instance Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa367797)

[Installing Multiple Instances with Instance Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa369528)

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am trying to fetch the existing version using property and then using unInstallApllication().But unInstallApplication() is not working.Do you have any idea about the same.Following is the line : UninstallApplication(key, "/x", WAIT)